# How can I call Add-Migration without parameters

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-migrations

I have .net Core 3.1 solution with `WebApi` and `Persistance` projects. `WebApi` is the solution's startup project, `Persistance` is where `DbContext` is defined. After a lot of reading and trying stuff, I still cannot achieve the following:

1. `WebApi` stays as the solution's startup project.
2. `Migrations` folder with all the migrations classes is in the `Persistance` project.
3. Migrations can be generated from VS Package Manager Console by typing `Add-Migration <migration_name>` without any additional parameters like `-Project` or `-StartupProject`.
4. No need to change selection in the Package Manager Console `Default project` dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to achieve the same result but on MAC OS. Because Visual Studio on Mac is not like Window's, We use CLI commands. In my case I had Migration Classes in another project and startup was Api project just like you so i added this to my terminal :

```
alias migrationfortest='dotnet ef migrations add $1 --project /Users/user/Projects/test-web/Test.Infrastructure'
```

and you can call this simply by typing `migrationfortest "YOURMIGRATIONNAME"`

NOTE : For CLI command tools you should add [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet)